# I want to use one template inside another template to reuse it (Meteor blaze)

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am facing a problem with meteor blaze template. I want to use one template and its helper inside another template for reusability.

```
<template name = "some_template">
  .
  .
  .
</template>

<template name = "another_template">
  //here events are working but helpers are not working
  {{>some_template}}
</template>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate?
What exactly is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: Please add your helper code, otherwise this is hard guess

Comment: I am trying to reuse one template what I have made already inside another template.

Answer (score 0):

Arpit, first You should import that html file into `client/main.js` file. Then you can call template from other files or same file by  `{{> some_template}}`.